# What does "old code" for keyword abstract mean?

Tags: php, oop

I am new to php and learning OOP in php. One thing that i have found on the below reference link that **Old code that has no user-defined classes or functions named 'abstract' should run without modifications.**. Can anyone tell what does it mean ? Does it mean that in old version keyword **abstract** is not supported in old php or may be i am wrong ?

Reference Link: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is indeed a terribly misplaced fragment there in the manual…

The point is that PHP 5 introduces the new keyword `abstract` to annotate abstract classes. The important part here is that it's a *new keyword.* You cannot use reserved keywords for anything in your own code, e.g. `function abstract() {}`. If you have PHP 4 code, in which `abstract` was not a reserved keyword, then you may have declared such a function or class using the name "`abstract`". Such code would break in PHP 5.

Comment: We should probably either fix it or maybe just remove it entirely.

Comment: @PeeHaa That should be rewritten and/or included into the first paragraph somehow IMO. But since PHP 4 is long dead, removing it probably won't confuse anyone.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154339/discussion-on-answer-by-deceze-what-does-old-code-for-keyword-abstract-mean).